# Не обновляется БД после добавления записей в таблицу

Tags: c#, база-данных

Проект SaleProject отслеживает добавление в папку .csv файлов, если новый файл поступил, то его данные отправляются в таблицу БД. Ранее проект работал, когда бд создавалась в этом же проекте с помощью EF Code First. Теперь переделал проект в связи с тем, что данные должны отправляться в бд из нового проекта MvcSaleProject. Ошибок никаких нет, но данные в таблице не обновляются. Вот методы для SaleProject

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using MvcSaleProject.Models;

namespace SaleProject
{
    public class Methods
    {
        private const string Folder =         @"D:\epam\Tasks\l1\l1\SaleProject\bin\Debug";
        public static readonly FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new     FileSystemWatcher(Folder, "*.csv");
        public static DataTable GetTableCsv(string file)
        {
            var connection = new OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
Dbq=" + Folder + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False");
            var dt = new DataTable();
            var da = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from [" + file + "]", connection);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dt.TableName = file;
            return dt;
        }
        public static void ViewAbilities()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing program which tracks addition new .csv files in catalog. " +
                          "Info from files sent to database.");
            Run();
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') {}
        }
        public static void Run()
        {
            Watcher.Created += OnCreated;
            Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(CsvToDataBase, e.Name);
        }
        public static void CsvToDataBase(object file)
        {
            string path = (string) file;
            var dataTable = GetTableCsv(path);
            using (UsersContext dataBase = new UsersContext())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DateTime varTime = (DateTime) dataTable.Rows[i][0];
                    var record = new ArchiveRecord
                    {
                        Date = varTime,
                        Client = (string)dataTable.Rows[i][1],
                        Goods = (string)dataTable.Rows[i][2],
                        Amount = (int)dataTable.Rows[i][3]
                    };
                    dataBase.Archive.Add(record);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("In DataBase add new file {0} on thread {1}", dataTable.TableName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                dataBase.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс Program SaleProject:

```
namespace SaleProject
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Methods.ViewAbilities();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот класс для БД в MvcSaleProject:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArchiveRecord> Archive { get; set; }

}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
[Table("Archive")]
public class ArchiveRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string Goods { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
}

public class LocalPasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class LoginModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class ExternalLogin
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Изменил в App.config connection на connection из MvcSaleProject - теперь появилась ошибка [image: ошибка]

Comment: Воспользуйтесь отладчиком и проверьте, вызывается ли вообще добавление.Приведите в вопросе connection string.

Comment: Для связи с бд(которая создалась с помощью Entity Framework Code First в проекте MvcSaleProject), я использую using (UsersContext dataBase = new UsersContext()) {}, обращаясь из проекта SaleProject

Comment: ваш код выглядит вполне рабочим. хотите помощи - сделайте то, что написано в моем комменте выше. Есть три варианта - не вызывается добавление, вызывается, но не в ту базу, вызывается, но база подключена через AttachDBFilename, и вы просто смотрите не в той папке. 1 - проверьте в отладке. 2, 3 - покажите connection string.

Comment: @Антон А connectionString у вас в каком из App.xaml проектов находится?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcSaleProject-20150430191346;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcSaleProject-20150430191346.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Добавление работает, походу не в ту бд смотрю

Comment: Спасибо, вроде пашет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая что, очевидных ошибок в приведенном коде нет, думаю нелишним будет проверить два пункта:

1 корректность строки connectionString, в ту ли базу вы пишите и имеется ли у вас доступ к ней.

2 Учитывая так же, что проекта два, нужно проверить что App.config конечного проекта, если я правильно понимаю это SaleProject, содержит:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="имя соединения" connectionString="ваш соединение" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Очень вероятно, что подобный раздел содержится в App.config проекта  MvcSaleProject, но результирующее приложение может использовать только собственные настройки, поэтому необходимо его перенести в проект SaleProject.

Comment: В App.config изменил коннекшин на тот, который в MvcSaleProject. Теперь появилась ошибка "Cannot attach the file"

Comment: скрин ошибки прикрепил к теме

Comment: @Антон, ??? в папке bin/Debug у вас есть файл aspnet-... .mdf,

Comment: В bin/debug у MvcSaleProject есть

Comment: @Антон, его ведь использует SaleProject, он должен быть там, если у вас будет несколько проектов, использующих MvcSaleProject, то в каждом из них должна содержатся ссылка на конкретный файл, либо созданный в этом проекте, либо существующий где-либо на диске.

Comment: существующий не во временной папке bin, а где нибудь по "постоянной прописке"? Кроме того, довольно странно что он не копируется, проверьте его свойства.

Comment: Вроде заработало, завтра на свежую голову всё проверю. А то сегодня уже насмотрелся ошибок)) за всё спасибо)